# Javascript Automatic Slideshow assist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well I recently integrated a slideshow which as I understood ((still a newbie with JS)) slide the pictures using opacity and focuses heavily on HTML DOM.
The only issue I have with this that I want to be able to get redirected to a new page containing the image that I click on.
Could someone explain to me how does this script works exactly and how could I add the possibility to redirect to the aforementioned page when I click with addEventListener and thanks in advance.

Javascript :

```
     (function() {

    function Slideshow( element ) {
        this.el = document.querySelector( element );
        this.init();
    }

    Slideshow.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            this.wrapper = this.el.querySelector( ".slider-wrapper" );
            this.slides = this.el.querySelectorAll( ".slide" );
            this.previous = this.el.querySelector( ".slider-previous" );
            this.next = this.el.querySelector( ".slider-next" );
            this.index = 0;
            this.total = this.slides.length;
            this.timer = null;

            this.action();
            this.stopStart();   
        },
        _slideTo: function( slide ) {
            var currentSlide = this.slides[slide];
            currentSlide.style.opacity = 1;

            for( var i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++ ) {
                var slide = this.slides[i];
                if( slide !== currentSlide ) {
                    slide.style.opacity = 0;
                }
            }
        },
        action: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.timer = setInterval(function() {
                self.index++;
                if( self.index == self.slides.length ) {
                    self.index = 0;
                }
                self._slideTo( self.index );

            }, 3000);
        },
        stopStart: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.el.addEventListener( "mouseover", function() {
                clearInterval( self.timer );
                self.timer = null;

            }, false);
            self.el.addEventListener( "mouseout", function() {
                self.action();

            }, false);
        }


    };

    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {

        var slider = new Slideshow( "#main-slider" );

    });


})();
```

Css :

```
.slider {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 2em auto;
}

.slider-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.slide {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 3s linear;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1.8px #000, 0px 0px 0px 10px #e7e5e4;
}

.slider-wrapper > .slide:first-child {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slider" id="main-slider">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <img src="i1.png" alt="First" class="slide" onclick="window.open('v1.html','new','height=60px;','width=6px','toolbar=no','menubar=no','scrollbars=0','location=no');")/><!-- les slides etc -->
        <img src="i2.png" alt="Second" class="slide" onclick="window.open('v2.html','new','height=60px;','width=6px','toolbar=no','menubar=no','scrollbars=0','location=no');")/>
        <img src="i3.png" alt="Third" class="slide" onclick="window.open('v3.html','new','height=60px;','width=6px','toolbar=no','menubar=no','scrollbars=0','location=no');")/>
        <img src="i4.png" alt="Fourth" class="slide" id="t";/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the height spec for window.open() has to be min 100, and without px. Example:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");
```

Another way to open in a new window, is to wrap the 'img' tag in an 'a' tag, and make the target blank. Example:

```
<a href="v1.html" target="_blank">
  <img src="i1.png" alt="First" class="slide"/>
</a>
```

But that may not be what you are looking for, as you seem to want the window to be 60px high and 6px wide.

Also, if you need to use window.open(), don't do:

```
<img src="i1.png" alt="First" class="slide" onclick="window.open('v1.html','new','height=60;','width=6','toolbar=no','menubar=no','scrollbars=0','location=no');")/>
```

instead, do:

```
<img src="i1.png" alt="First" class="slide" onclick="window.open('v1.html','new','height=60,width=6,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=0,location=no');")/>
```

**Edit:**

Here is a working example.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrxeRB
This will work.

Comment: First of all Thank you for your answer however when I use the the hyperlink the slideshow doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Also, please specify what about the slideshow isn't working.

Comment: The issue with my code that it simply won't work with the hyperlink because it places all the images stacked behind each other and manipulate opacity therefore adding Hyperlink would only affect a single image.